# Bezier curve lacking handles

Tags: bezier-curves

So I wanted some stiff hair particles, but a little twisted. I made hair, added a vortex, baked to the frame/shape I wanted, and then I hit `Convert`. This turned it into a mesh, but the mesh was like invisible lines in render. It did not retain the shape from the `Cycle Settings`. From a few searches, I decided to convert the mesh to a curve (`ALT+C` - Curve from Mesh) and bevel.

However, the problem now is that the resulting tubes have jagged edges. I went into `Edit mode` and found that none of the Control Points have any Handles. How can I get/create handles in a curve? Tried setting all the Handle Types.

Comment: perhaps T menu > Tools > Set Spline Type > Bezier? Also, in the N menu make sure that Handle is enable in the Curve Display

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now just to get this to follow the armature...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution is T menu > Tools > Set Spline Type > Bezier. Also, in the N menu make sure that Handle is enabled in the Curve Display